How to automate pdb commands at a breakpoint() or set_trace()?
I have two complicated Python functions that follow each other.  At the end of the second, I would like to occasionally call breakpoint() based on some values.  To speed up my debugging, I can print these values to the console before calling breakpoint().  I would also like to print the value of a variable before it entered the complicated functions.  Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/50660489/2336725, I think the following should work:
import pdb
import io

output = io.StringIO()
pdb_script = io.StringIO('up 1 ;; p start ;; continue')
mypdb = pdb.Pdb(stdin=pdb_script, stdout=output)

def complicated_function(input):
    return input + 10

def complicated_other_function(input):
    if input == 12:
        print('input is',input)  # correctly shows 12
        print('start is')  # how to show this is 2?
        mypdb.set_trace()
        breakpoint()
    return 1 / ( input - 12 )

for start in range(5):
    value = complicated_function(start)
    complicated_other_function(value)

Unfortunately, everything related to mypdb is ignored, and the script proceeds straight to the breakpoint().  Is there a way to access the value of a variable in an older frame without typing in the pdb commands after execution has stopped?
